# Captalizing Strings Automatically before Persist

Tags: java, string, jpa, eclipselink

I have the following situation: my application needs to save all the strings typed by the user capitalized on the database, no matter how the user types it, the application needs to capitalize everything before saving it.

I know I could just call the toUpperCase() method on every string before saving it, or call it on every setter method, but I really don't want to do that, I'm looking for a more automatic way to do it without having to change too much code on the application.

I'm using JSF, JPA2, Eclipselink and EJB3.

Does anyone have any suggestion?

Comment: Personally I don't think adding one line of code would be "changing too much code"

Comment: Its is one line for each string I'm saving

Comment: If you would use [Hibernate](http://hibernate.org), then you could write an [Interceptor](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.6/javadocs/org/hibernate/Interceptor.html), which could intercept the persisting, and do your logic, before the transaction commits. In eclipselink, I don't know about such a solution, so probably you will have to change your strings everywhere.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use lifecycle event listeners for this. There are several ways to implement it:

1: default listeners:

```
    public class StringCapListener {
    @PrePersist
    @PreUpdate
    public void capitalize(Object o) {
      // capitalize string attributes
    }
    ...
```

For the capitalizing you will either need to use reflection (extracting all string fields and changing their value) or let your entities implement an interface.

If you are using the listener only on several entities, prefer using the `@EntityListeners` annotation on the entity classes. In order to use the listeners on all entities, use default listeners. Unfortunately, you can only define them in XML:

```
<entity-mappings ...>
    <persistence-unit-metadata>
        <persistence-unit-defaults>
            <entity-listeners>
                <entity-listener class="com.example.StringCapListener">
```

2: inherited listener method

Let your entities derive from a `BaseEntity` of sorts. This base class can implement a listener method that is triggered on persist & update.

```
    @PrePersist
    @PreUpdate
    public void capitalize(BaseEntity o) {
      // capitalize string attributes
    }
```

You will need to employ the same reflection magic to get and change all string attributes.

Comment: I used a default listener as you said, everything worked fine with the `@PrePersist` listener, but when I'm updating an object it doesn't work, the `@PreUpdate` method is called normally, and it is modifying the strings correctly, but it isn't updating the database with the modified values, instead it is saving the object as it was before the `@PreUpdate` method, any ideas on how to solve it?

Comment: This is strange, the PreUpdate callback is specified to be called before the flush/commit. Since the method is firing on update, and everything works for PrePersist I am puzzled. Perhaps you could use two listener methods to be absolutely sure and could you post the relevant code just in case?

Comment: I've created a new question with the code, here is the link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26045966/preupdate-callback-does-not-work

Answer (score -1):

I'm thinking of an interface

```
public interface Processor<TResult, TInput> {
    public TResult process(TInput input);
}

public class StringProcessor implements Processor<String, String> {
    public String process(String input) {
         return input.toUpperCase();
    }
}
```

Then you'd call the interface on every string before persisting it

```
//...
public void persistString(String input) {
     input = processor.process(input);
     // Persistence logic
}
```