# Field values are not being modified on PreUpdate callback

Tags: java, jpa, ejb, entitymanager, entitylisteners

I've defined the following class as as default Entity Listener, so every time I call the persist() or merge() methods this code will be executed automatically:

```
public class StringProcessorListener {

    @PrePersist
    @PreUpdate
    public void formatStrings(Object object) {
        try {
            for (Field f : object.getClass().getDeclaredFields()) {
                if (f.getType().equals(String.class)) {
                    f.setAccessible(true);
                    if (f.get(object) != null) {
                        f.set(object, f.get(object).toString().toUpperCase());
                    }
                }
            }
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(StringProcessorListener.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
    }
}
```

The purpose of this is to capitalize all the strings of an object before insert it into the database. The @PrePersist worked fine, the method modifies all the strings and it is saved capitalized on the database, but when I try to update an object it didn't work so well, the method is called normally and it also modifies the strings, but instead of saving the modified object on the database, it is saving the object as it was before this method.

Any ideas on how to solve this?

**Update:**

I solved it using a `DescriptorEvent`, it gave me access to the ObjectChangeSet and I could update it manually, then the values were correctly saved on the database.

Comment: How about doing an UpperCase() before you save or update, like in the entity setUser you can just do user = user.uppercase()

Comment: I could have done it, but I would have to change a lot of code on my project, I have more than 300 entities, and it would require too much work to do it.

Comment: Does the save work if you just put PreUpdate annotation there?

Comment: I found here http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Java_Persistence/Advanced_Topics#Events that PreUpdate will not work with merge()

Comment: Thanks for the help, I think I'll have to find another way.

Comment: This should work - the wiki link seems misworded, as the event should fire before the update statement is issued.  So while the event does not fire with merge, it should still get fired when the transaction commits or flushes, so that the case changes are pushed to the database.  What environment are you running this on?

Answer (score 1):

If running in a server environment or using an agent for weaving, EclipseLink will default to using change tracking where possible for performance reasons.  If so, your method of directly setting the values in the object would bypass the woven changetracking code, so EclipseLink isn't aware of the changes.  O persist, it uses all values directly from the object, while on updates, it only uses the changed fields, and it would only know about changes through the changetracking listeners.  You will either need to use method access to set these fields, or turn off change tracking:
http://eclipse.org/eclipselink/documentation/2.5/jpa/extensions/a_changetracking.htm